# Next.js nested dynamic routes with specific settings page for each route

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have a web app built with Next.js and TypeScript. This app can show an unlimited number of nested paths, such as:

`/groups/sports/team-sports/football`
`educations/elementary/class/group/pre-school/kids`
`/members/senior-high-school/teachers/mathematics/algebra`
The first part of the path is the main category, and the following parts are subcategories. These paths all show the same page design, but with different data.

I want to add a new page like 'settings' at the end of these paths, for example:

`/groups/sports/team-sports/football/-/settings`
`educations/elementary/class/group/pre-school/kids/-/settings`
`/members/senior-high-school/teachers/mathematics/algebra/-/people`
How can I do this so that the 'settings' page shows the settings page?

Answer (score 0):

In your pages folder, create a file called `[...settings].js` and affect to it the page you want to show the Settings.

- But you should be careful here as the data that separate which settings you wanna show, will come only from the url.